# Is it possible to Pass Twitter API Access tokens directly to browser URL

Tags: api, url, twitter, token

**I'm trying to get a "DEFINITIVE" answer for this. From what I've read the answer would seem to be "No", but I just wanted to make sure while getting a better understanding of how interacting with Twitter's API works because with GitHub I'm able to receive responses (raw data) simply by modifying the URL. If someone knows of a link that "specifically" addresses this that I can read that would be greatly appreciated  -- I've read virtually all of Twitter's API documentation, but inclusion of your credentials as a browser request (as opposed to an HTTP Get request using curl, php, etc.) doesn't seem to be specifically addressed** and I wanted to know if there was a way to do this without having to download anything although I've already successfully grabbed tweets via a Python script already.

To provide more clarity, is there something similar to the following with the appropriate syntax that would allow me to access tweets:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=TwitterUser&count=50&[ConsumerKey]&[ConsumerSecret]&[AccessToken]&[AccessSecret]
```

Please take note that I have appended:

```
&[ConsumerKey]&[ConsumerSecret]&[AccessToken]&[AccessSecret]
```

But I am asking if there is a specific syntax I can use in order to include those parameters to be taken directly to a page of tweets, as opposed to doing it exclusively by scripting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The Twitter API itself enforces clients use OAuth access tokens.

You can build this yourself, or it seems there are services that provide this for you like https://github.com/timwhitlock/php-twitter-proxy/tree/master/1.1 or http://supertweet.net/.  No idea if they work.

Twitter itself uses CORS to expose the API to its own sites via javascript, but that is locked down to sites like tweetdeck and doesn't work in the browser bar anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much, Yuri. Upon further reading I found a similar answer awhile reading up on wget and cURL. Yours, however, is definitely more specific and really helped me out! Thanks again, Yuri.